# Left outer join failed

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi This Query is not working , If i added on condition on `VBFA.VBTYP_N = 'Q'` and it is giving `null` data And Same result if added in where condition . Both cases are same result

I need fetch data from left table even on condition failed

```
ORDER_DATA = SELECT

          VBRP.MATNR AS ITEM,
          VBRP.ARKTX AS ITEMDESCRIPTION,
          VBAK.ERDAT AS ORDERDATE,
          VBAK.VBELN AS ORDERNUMBER,
          VBRK.FKDAT AS INVOICEDATE,
          VBRK.VBELN AS INVOICENUMBER ,
          VBRP.FKIMG AS QUANTITY,
          VBRP.VRKME AS UOM,
          VBFA.RFMNG AS PICKUNIT
          FROM  VBAP

          INNER JOIN VBAK
          ON   VBAP.MANDT = VBAK.MANDT
          AND  VBAP.VBELN = VBAK.VBELN

          LEFT  OUTER JOIN VBRP
          ON  VBAP.MANDT = VBRP.MANDT
          AND VBAP.VBELN = VBRP.AUBEL
          AND VBAP.POSNR = VBRP.AUPOS

         LEFT OUTER JOIN VBFA

          ON  VBRP.VGBEL = VBFA.VBELV
          AND  VBRP.VGPOS = VBFA.POSNV
          AND VBFA.VBTYP_N = 'Q'

          INNER JOIN VBRK
          ON  VBRP.MANDT = VBRK.MANDT
          AND VBRP.VBELN = VBRK.VBELN






          WHERE VBAP.MANDT = :CLNT AND
                VBAK.MANDT = :CLNT AND
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: You'll have to show us you database scheme, some sample data and your desired output to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have NULL values in your VBFA.VBTYP_N column and it is the reason of failed join condition, then you can try to use something like this:
AND (VBFA.VBTYP_N IS NULL OR VBFA.VBTYP_N = 'Q')